# How to read a json file from GCP bucket using java

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow, google-dataflow

I am trying to read a json file and map to Gson object on fly, tired reading using FileReader which is not working, also tried multiple ways but no luck.. can someone help me in reading from gcp bucket

```
public static Response[] getJsonData() {

        try {

            JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new FileReader("gs://01test_dataflow/data_schema.json"));
            Response[] response = new Gson().fromJson(reader, Response[].class);

            return response;

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "read a json file and map to Gson object on *(sic)* fly"?

Comment: Gson maps the josn into pojo classes

Comment: Reading json file form gcp bucket using java should be sufficient

Comment: Use the google cloud JAVA libraries for GCS to download the file and then read it from the local location